# EF setting 1 to 0..1 Navigation Property throws exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a model where a `Person` *can* have an `Key` associated but a `Key` *must* have `Person` (cascade), modeled by following code-first model with Navigation Properties:

```
class Key {
  [Key]
  public string Code { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

class Person {
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public virtual Key Key { get; set; }
}
```

however, when there is a `Person` entity with a `Key`, replacing the `Key` with another one throws an exception:

```
Person person = ctx.People.First(); //ctx loaded with ctx.People.Load(); ctx.Keys.Load()
person.Key = new Key () { Code = "Foo" };
ctx.SaveChanges(); //<---exception thrown
```

with message:

> A relationship from the 'Key_Person' AssociationSet is in the
>   'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding
>   'Key_Person_Source' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

which does not make sense: `Key` is in deleted state(first sentence)? Good. I want that. But why it cannot be replaced by another `Key` or deleted if there is `[Required]` attribute I am at loss(second sentence). 
Manually removing current `Key` works:

```
Person person = ctx.People.First();
if(person.Key != null) ctx.Keys.Remove(person.Key);//<---manually update
person.Key = new Key () { Code = "Foo" };
ctx.SaveChanges(); //<---no exception
```

But shouldn't be the reason to use Navigation Properties avoiding manually updating DBSets in the first place?

Comment: It might be something related to change EF tracking and lazy loading (and the limited EF support for this type of relationship). Did you try `var person = ctx.People.Include(p => p.Key);` before modifying the `Key`?

Comment: @IvanStoev the context is fully loaded beforehand (omitted for brevity): `ctx.People.Load(); ctx.Keys.Load()` - that should be at least equivalent?

Comment: In theory - yes. In practice - who knows :) The "Manually removing" example is missing part of the code before the `=`, what is there? Also which of the two entities is the dependent (which table has the FK)?

Comment: @IvanStoev checked in debugger, the navigation property is loaded (and since removing work, it must be even without debugging). The `Key` has foreign key generated column, `Person` does not.

Comment: I don't know what to say - one-to-many also has similar behavior when removing child from parent collection. Logically it can be treated as deletion, but EF requires you to manually delete it (`Remove` from the corresponding `DbSet`). I guess you should live with that behavior. And in general avoid one-to-one FK relationships in EF6 where possible.

Comment: Weird. In your first example I would have expected the `Key` record to be updated. What happens if you don't preload data and query the `Person` using `Include(p => p.Key)`?

Comment: @GertArnold sadly, no change